# media queries in SASS compiling but not displaying

Tags: css, sass, width

I'm building a website with responsive media queries. I have one query that adapts if the screen is 900px or less (max-width). I've created a mixin to help with managing my queries.

```
@mixin responsive ($breakpoint){
@if $breakpoint == phone {
    @media(max-width: 37.5em){ @content };  // 600px
}
@if $breakpoint == tab-port {
    @media(max-width: 56.25em){ @content };   // 900px
}
@if $breakpoint == tab-land {
    @media(max-width: 75em){ @content };  // 1200px
}
@if $breakpoint == big-desktop {
    @media(min-width: 112.5em){ @content };  // 1800px
 }
}
```

So, then I'll use it within SASS

```
.div{

&__container {
    display: flex;
    padding: 5rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;

    @include responsive(tab-port) {
        width: 90%;
    }

}
```

It compiles correctly

```
.div__container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%; 
}
  @media (max-width: 56.25em) {

.div__container {

 width: 90%; 
 } 
}
```

But it doesn't actually show up on the website any different at 900px or less. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The compiled CSS looks fine, are you sure nothing is happening? inspect te element to be sure, put more visible code like `font-weight: bold` to be extra sure and resize your viewport manually (why do you use `em` values if you explicitly want `px`?)

Answer (score 0):

Media queries work fine, but because of padding width is bugger than 80%.

```
.div {

  &__container {
      display: flex;
      // padding: 5rem;
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 80%;
      border: 5px solid red;

      @include responsive(tab-port) {
          width: 90%;
          border: 5px solid blue;
      }

  }
}
```

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MxgaVR

Comment: I see your codepen works, but when I try to put the same thing within my code and compile it, nothing actually changes in the browser. The queries don't appear within the Chrome debugger, and I've tried adding a border and transforming the text to uppercase to make any changes more noticeable. Nothing seems to be changing when I manually change the page's size within the debugger.  Edit: I see the changes when I manually move the browser window itself outside of the debugger. Why would this change?

Comment: some time chrome debugger has bugs. i saw it too many. try reinstall chrome

Comment: how ironic lol.... okay, I'll try that and see what happens. For the time being, my queries should work fine, it's not a problem with my code?